# Replace multiple placeholders with their corresponding values in string

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a command to make a custom welcome message so when someone say changes the title to the custom placeholder `{user.id}` it would change the title to the joining users ID

I tried `${(cardText, placeholders)}` but that just returns [object Object] in the embed

So cardText is `{user.tag}` so i want it to look in `placeholders` and see if there is a placeholder in the string and if there is change it to the right  value so in this case it would change it to member.user.tag

Code:

```
module.exports = async (client, member) => {
    
    const guildSchema = require('../../models/guildSchema');
    const data = await guildSchema.findOne({
        id: member.guild.id
    });
 
    const placeholders = {
        '{client.avatar}': client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
        '{client.username}': client.user.username,
        '{client.mention}': client.user,
        '{client.tag}': client.user.tag,
        '{client.id}': client.user.id,
 
        '{user.avatar}': member.user.displayAvatarURL(),
        '{user.username}': member.user.username,
        '{user.mention}': member.user,
        '{user.tag}': member.user.tag,
        '{user.id}': member.user.id,
 
        '{guild.memberCount}': member.guild.memberCount,
        '{guild.icon}': member.guild.iconURL,
        '{guild.name}': member.guild.name,
        '{guild.id}': member.guild.id,
    };
    
    const cardTitle = (data.welcome.title === null) ? 'Welcome To The Server' : data.welcome.title;
    const cardText = (data.welcome.text === null) ? '{user.tag}' : data.welcome.text;
    const cardSubtitle = (data.welcome.subtitle === null) ? 'Member Count: {guild.memberCount}' : data.welcome.text;
 
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${(cardTitle, placeholders)}`),
        .setDescription(`${(cardText, placeholders)}`),
        .setFooter(`${(cardSubtitle, placeholders)}`),
 
        channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Your `cardTitle` seems to always be a string, so you could just use `\`${cardTitle}\``for it. For a JSON Object, you can simply `JSON.stringify()` it.

Comment: not just for the cardTitle and the cardTitle isnt always just  a string also the cardText, what would i add JSON.stringify() to

Comment: You would have to provide a bit more detail on what is it that you want, possibly with screenshots/mockups and what's going on right now. It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Why are the keys for `placeholders` in the form of `{...}`?

Comment: i have a custom welcome message command and i want people to use the placeholders like {member.username} in the welcome message but im struggling to output it im using `{...}` so it doesnt turn it into a string

Comment: What should the custom welcome message command output look like?

Comment: well when putting say `{user.id}` as the title it would put `member.user.id` so the title would be something like `43975220543` (whatever the joining members id is)

Comment: Please update your question with a detailed example use case of this code. It is a bit confusing to understand what you need. Thank you.

Comment: updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with OP's code was that the example they were following had some conventions that let users have templating in their message text denoted by `{}`.

For example, in `'Member Count: {guild.memberCount}'`, the `{guild.memberCount}` would be replaced to give us `'Member Count: 123'` or something.

But the function to replace this placeholders was missing from their source.

Hence, a parsing function such as:

```js
const replacePlaceholder = (template, placeholders) => {
  //if there is no placeholder, return.
  if (template.indexOf('{') === -1) return template;
  //get the string inside the {}
  const toReplace = template.slice(
    template.indexOf('{'),
    template.indexOf('}') + 1
  );

  //keep replacing until { character is not found.
  return replacePlaceholder(
    template.replace(toReplace, placeholders[toReplace]),
    placeholders
  );
};
```

was needed. In this context, it also makes sense why OP was using:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`${(cardTitle, placeholders)}`),
  .setDescription(`${(cardText, placeholders)}`),
  .setFooter(`${(cardSubtitle, placeholders)}`),
```

They were originally function calls such as:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`${replacePlaceholder(cardTitle, placeholders)}`),
  .setDescription(`${replacePlaceholder(cardText, placeholders)}`),
  .setFooter(`${replacePlaceholder(cardSubtitle, placeholders)}`),
```

Comment: im still confused how to implement this into my code, `cardTitle`, `cardText` etc is a different value for every guild

Comment: So `client` and `member` you receive as arguments for this exported function, correct? So those wouldn't be a problem, and so does `placeholders.guild` because you get it as `member.guild`

Comment: how would i add it to an embed though

Comment: By using `Discord.MessageEmbed()` just like you did in your question. Instead of `\`${(cardTitle, placeholders)}\``, you use `placeholders.user.id`, etc.

Comment: i cant use `placeholders.user.id` though because its not always gonna be that value, in this command it goes into the database and sees what the guild owner changed the welcome message to

Comment: Is that not why you use the ternary operators in `cardTitle = (data.welcome.title === null) ? 'Welcome To The Server' : data.welcome.title;` and others? That line should be fine.

Comment: what those lines do is look in the database to see if the guild owner has set a custom welcome message, if there isnt then set the cardtitle to 'welcome to the server' which is the default message and if its not then set the welcome message to whatever they set it as which might include those placeholders

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244943/discussion-between-csharp-and-hydrome).

Answer (score 0):

Let's use regular expressions to do the matching for us. Because your keys have characters that have special meaning in regular expressions (`{` and `}`), we'll need to escape those.

Pulled from [escape-string-regexp](https://github.com/sindresorhus/escape-string-regexp/blob/main/index.js):

```
const escapeRegex = (string) => string
    .replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&')
    .replace(/-/g, '\\x2d');
```

Then let's write a function that takes a template and the placeholders. We should create a regular expression from the placeholder like this:

```
const regex = new RegExp("(" + Object.keys(placeholders).map(escapeRegex).join("|") + ")", "g");
```

For each key in the placeholders object, we escape the special characters, and join it all with `|`, wrapping the result in parentheses. Then we give it the `g` (global) flag so it provides us all the matches.

For you, this generated regex would look something like:

```
/(\{client.avatar\}|\{client.username\}|...|\{guild.id\})/g
```

Lastly, we want to use this regex and replace all occurrences of placeholders with their corresponding value.

```
return template.replace(regex, (_, match) => placeholders[match]);
```

So the full code looks like this:

```
const escapeRegex = (string) => string
    .replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&')
    .replace(/-/g, '\\x2d');

function fill(template, placeholders) {
    const regex = new RegExp("(" + Object.keys(placeholders).map(escapeRegex).join("|") + ")", "g");

    return template.replace(regex, (_, match) => placeholders[match]);
}
```

Example usage:

```
fill("My name is {name}!", { "{name}": "Kelly" }); // "My name is Kelly!"
```

You can try it out [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYkPzN), just click the link and hit "Run". To the right you'll see the output.

---

Why don't we just use something like this:

```
template
    .replaceAll("{client.avatar}", placeholders["{client.avatar}"])
    .replaceAll("{client.username}", placeholders["{client.username}"])
    .replaceAll(...)
    // ...
```

Well first of all, that's not really DRY, is it? You could help with that using a loop:

```
for (const [place, value] of Object.entries(placeholders)) {
    template = template.replaceAll(place, value);
}
```

But then there's a catch! What if some placeholder's value contained another placeholder? Then you'd replace the new placeholder with a new value! This might lead to unexpected behavior, which is why I suggested using this solution instead; replace *all* matches at once, preventing this from happening.

Placeholders:

```
{bar} => i love {foo}
{foo} => 42
```

And then:

```
say {bar}
say i love {foo}
say i love 42
```

Uh oh!